# Search and cut the word from the file

Tags: shell, unix

I have my file content like this

> JSESSIONID    "ajax:2316582834410000000"

From this file i need to get only ajax:2316582834410000000 this value and store into variable. How to write a shell script or unix commands for the above scenario. 2316.... is dynamic value only ajax is static value so everytime the value will get change.

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk:

```
awk -F'"' 'index($1, "JSESSIONID"){print $2}' file
ajax:2316582834410000000
```

To store this value in a variable:

```
val=`awk -F'"' 'index($1, "JSESSIONID"){print $2}' file`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
v=$( awk -F\" '/^JSESSIONID/{print $2}' input-file )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myvar=`echo JSESSIONID "ajax:2316582834410000000" | awk '{print $2}'`
```

OR (without backticks)

```
myvar=$(echo JSESSIONID "ajax:2316582834410000000" | awk '{print $2}')
```

OR

```
myvar=$(echo JSESSIONID "ajax:2316582834410000000" | cut -d' ' -f2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cut` command here:-

```
echo JSESSIONID "ajax:2316582834410000000" | cut -d' ' -f2
```

output:-**ajax:2316582834410000000**